# Will using only onboard Intel GPU to connect to external monitor harm my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, gpu

I have a 2010 MacBook Pro 2010 with a faulty Nvidia GPU that used to crash the laptop every now and then.

I than ran a program called MBPMid2010-GPU-Fix-0.6.1, which bypassed the Nvidia GPU. So far, I haven't had a single crash. I read somewhere that after bypassing Nvidia GPU, I won't be able to use external monitor.

However when I tried, it worked. I want to know if it is safe to use an external monitor using only onboard Intel HD Graphics (288 MB)?

Comment: Welcome! I don't think this is possible. As the authors of the tool you used say, external screens cannot be used with the Intel GPU: https://github.com/julian-poidevin/MBPMid2010_GPUFix/blob/master/FAQ.md#q-the-fix-does-not-work-when-an-external-screen-is-plugged. You can use a tool like [this](https://github.com/steveschow/gfxCardStatus) to check what GPU is being used.

Comment: Could you edit to elaborate what you mean by "safe" - your Mac needs a repair and you're making changes to the firmware, so are you asking if that was safe to do? (for whatever definition of safe)

Comment: The external monitor works for me. I patched it again. By "safe" i meant, is there ne risk of intel graphics heatin up too much and frying?

Comment: found the answers at git hub.

"There is absolutely no software way to get this working with external monitor. When external monitor is plugged, the moidifications made by my patch are overridden by the hardware."